# crash when the original file path has reserved characters

Tags: c, gstreamer

I write app to record from tv station with Gstreamer:

pipeline create filesink with:

```
    #include <gio/gio.h>


    Encoder* recording_start (const char* filename)
    {

    ------------------------------------------------------------
        GstElement *filesink;
        gchar *path;

        filesink = gst_element_factory_make ("filesink", NULL);
        g_return_val_if_fail (filesink != NULL, NULL);

        path = g_strdup_printf("%s.mov", filename);

        g_object_set(G_OBJECT(filesink), "location", path, NULL);

        gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (pipeline), source, encodebin, filesink, NULL);

        if (!gst_element_link_many (source, encodebin, filesink, NULL)) {
            gst_object_unref (pipeline);
            g_return_val_if_reached (NULL);
        }

        gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

        Encoder *encoder = g_malloc0(sizeof(Encoder));

        Encoder->filename = path;

        return encoder;
    }
```

File name of recording station is generate by:

```
    /*  args for this format are:
     *  path
     *  station title
     *  time
     */

    char *filename = g_strdup_printf (_("%s/%s_%s.mov"), destination, station, time);
```

I use GFile for queries information about recorded file (pointer to recrding file):

```
    file = g_file_new_for_path (encoder->filename);
```

user can select station which they want to record from combo box e.g:

```
            --------------
            | STATION 1  |
            --------------
            | STATION 2  |
            --------------
            | STATION 3  |
            --------------
```

when station name contains the following combination of characters: "< /" e.g:

```
            -----------------------
            | Canal Algérie </ 10  |
            -----------------------
```

application get error:

```
    ERROR: from element /GstFileSink:filesink3: Could not open file "/home/ubuntu/</_20130728-044308.mov" for writing.
    Additional debug info:
    gstfilesink.c(420): gst_file_sink_open_file (): /GstPipeline:pipeline/GstFileSink:filesink3:
    system error: No such file or directory
```

and then crash

Why app crash when the original file path has reserved characters or don't exist (GIO returns a valid path)?

If I remove "<" from station name: "Canal Algérie / 10", all is fine and app don't crash.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your program does not *crash*, it exits correctly, with a clear error message stating the exact problem.

You are copying the station name into a string that is going to be used as a file name. As you already observed, the station name may contain characters that are invalid for a file name. Remove these characters from the filename, or replace them with a valid character, to solve the problem.

I am not sure why either GIO fails to pick up the bad path. There are several possibilities: it could be an honest error in the library, or may it only checks if the path *could be* valid -- i.e., all of its components are -- without checking in depth if the path, and its subpaths, actually exist. (Although surely the character `<` in itself ought to throw an error.)